# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 not working correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I get the below error message when I use Google Maps JavaScript API:

> This site overrides Array.from() with an implementation that doesn't support iterables, which could cause Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to not work correctly.

What causes this? And how do I fix this? Could this be the reason why Google Map is not displaying although the API Key is checked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to not work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58158510/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-to-not-work-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

you can write a custom Polyfill for the Array.From:

**Step 1**: Download the file from the link:-
[arrayFrom.ts](https://gist.github.com/NikitaGp/48bf94957913cc2a76e098547c26e087)

**Step 2:** Save it somewhere in your project.

**Step 3:** Give the file path in your polyfills.ts file just like I did it:

**import 'src/app/library/custom-polyfills/arrayFrom';**

I hope this will solve your problem :) .

Answer (score -1):

You have not specified the other JS Libraries that your project is using.
This is actually an issue on IE11 with Google Maps Version of 3.37. You can check [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138963477)

This error might also come if your project is using `core-js`. Reference [Here](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/618)

Answer (score -1):

It seems this a compatibility issue with ***ES6 implementation*** and "Array.from()" as mentioned in this [**comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58158510/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-to-not-work-correctly).

Comment: Please see my comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58158510/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-to-not-work-correctly/58703775#58703775

Comment: is there actually a workaround for this? I'm still getting this error using a common Polyfill, but I'm not sure how to fix it (IE 11)