# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to not work correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, qualtrics

I get the below error message from the console when I try to implement Google Maps to my Qualtrics survey. API Key works properly:

> "This site overrides Array.from() with an implementation that doesn't
>   support iterables, which could cause Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to
>   not work correctly."

AND this is my code (ignore my API key):

I am not using any array, so I am not sure where the problem is coming from...

```js
/*
 * Qualtrics Google Map Lat/Long Collector
 * Version 1.4
 *
 * Written by George Walker <george@georgewwalker.com>
 * Get the latest from GitHub: https://github.com/pkmnct/qualtrics-google-map-lat-long/releases
 *
 * This JavaScript allows a Qualtrics user to collect a lat/long from a
 * Google Map in a survey. To use it, create a new "Text Entry" question,
 * then add this JavaScript to the question. You can set variables below.
 * These include the lattitude and longitude to center the map at, the
 * zoom level of the map, and the text to display when hovering over the
 * map's pin. It also includes the width and height of the map.
 */

// Enter your Google Map API key in this variable:
var googleMapAPIKey = "MyKey";

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
// --- User Variables, set these: ---
    var mapCenterLat = 39.1836;
    var mapCenterLng = -96.5717;
    var mapZoom = 16; // See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#zoom-levels for help.
    var pinTitle = "Move pin to correct location"; // This is displayed when hovering over the pin on the map.


    var mapWidth = "100%";
    var mapHeight = "300px";

    var locationInputWidth = "96%";
    var locationInputMargin = "2%";
    var locationInputPadding = "15px";

    var enableAutocompleteField = true;
    var invalidLocationAlertText = "Please choose a location from the search dropdown. If your location doesn't appear in the search, enter a nearby location and move the pin to the correct location.";

    // --- End of User Variables ---

    // Get the data entry box and store it in a variable
    var dataBox = document.getElementById("QR~" + this.questionId);

    // Get the question container and store it in a variable.
    var questionContainer = this.getQuestionContainer();

    // Need to be able to access the marker to update it later.
    var marker;

    if (enableAutocompleteField) {
        // Create a search box
        try {
            var locationInput = document.createElement('input');
            locationInput.setAttribute("id", this.questionId + "-locationInput");
            locationInput.style.width = locationInputWidth;
            locationInput.style.margin = locationInputMargin;
            locationInput.style.padding = locationInputPadding;
            questionContainer.appendChild(locationInput);
            var locationInputID = this.questionId + "-locationInput";
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Unable to create places autocomplete field. Details: " + err);
            alert("An error occurred creating the input field.");
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a map object and append it to the question container.
        var mapObject = document.createElement('div');
        mapObject.setAttribute("id", this.questionId + "-map");
        mapObject.style.width = mapWidth;
        mapObject.style.height = mapHeight;
        questionContainer.appendChild(mapObject);
        var mapID = this.questionId + "-map";
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Unable to create map object. Details: " + err);
        alert("An error occurred creating the map.");
    }

    // Hide the data box
    try {
        dataBox.style.display = 'none';
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Unable to hide data box.");
    }

    // This function calls itself once per second until the Google Maps API is loaded, then it displays the map.
    function displayMap() {
        try {

            if (enableAutocompleteField) {
                var locationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(locationInput);

                // Whenever the inputs change, set the locationLatLong
                google.maps.event.addListener(locationAutocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                    var place = locationAutocomplete.getPlace();

                    if (!place.geometry) {
                        alert(invalidLocationAlertText);
                    } else {
                        var locationLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng());
                        marker.setPosition(locationLatLong);
                        map.panTo(locationLatLong);
                        dataBox.value = '{"lat": "' + place.geometry.location.lat() + '", "long": "' + place.geometry.location.lng() + '"}';
                    }
                });
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapID), {
                center: {
                    lat: mapCenterLat,
                    lng: mapCenterLng
                },
                zoom: mapZoom
            });

            // Create a new marker in the center of the map.
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                draggable: true,
                position: {
                    lat: mapCenterLat,
                    lng: mapCenterLng
                },
                map: map,
                title: pinTitle
            });

            // When the pin is clicked, store the lat/lng
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
                dataBox.value = '{"lat": "' + this.getPosition().lat() + '", "long": "' + this.getPosition().lng() + '"}';
            });

            // When the pin is dragged, store the lat/lng where it ends
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
                dataBox.value = '{"lat": "' + this.getPosition().lat() + '", "long": "' + this.getPosition().lng() + '"}';
            });
        } catch (err) {
            setTimeout(displayMap, 1000);
        }
    }
    displayMap();

});

// Load the Google Maps API if it is not already loaded.
try {
    if (typeof googleMapJS == 'undefined') {
        var googleMapJS;
        if (googleMapJS == null) {
            googleMapJS = document.createElement('script');
            if (googleMapAPIKey == "MyKey" || googleMapAPIKey == null) {
                googleMapJS.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey';
            } else {
                googleMapJS.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey';
                //googleMapJS.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + googleMapAPIKey;
            }
            document.head.appendChild(googleMapJS);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Map already loaded.");
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Unable to load Google Maps API. Details: " + err);
    alert("Unable to load Google Maps API.");
}
```

Comment: The problem is in some third party library that implements its own Array.from() method that is not compatible with standard ES6 implementation of Array.from() described in  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/from. You should detect which library introduces the non-standard Array.from() and remove it in order to allow Google Maps API work correctly.

Comment: How do I detect the library?

Answer (score 4):

A similar issue has been reported in our **[Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/142335161)** and already been addressed by our Engineering team. As per latest comment:

> We've just submitted an update for this. The check is now more
>   explicit and will cover your use case: Array.from(new Set([42]))[0]
>   !== 42 ... warn
>
> This will be available in an upcoming weekly release

**Public Issue Tracker** is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects. You can learn more here https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same errors. I used Mootols Lightbox and Google Map framework together on my website. The Mootols had a javascript conflict with Google scripts. I removed the Mootols script and this Google message disappeared and Google Map works perfectly now.