# Why do I get an error 400 when switching my google maps to Satellite mode?

Tags: google-maps, http-status-code-400

When displaying a Google Map with Maps JavaScript API v3 activated, the default "Map" view works well, but the "Satellite" view does not : The image tiles read "Sorry, we have no imagery here".

I have two versions of the map : The public version works well either in Map mode or Satellite mode.
The private version, that requires login and allows for editing the custom stuff loaded onto the map, is the one that says "no imagery here" but only in Satellite mode.

When in private mode for editing, here is an example of working Map view :
[image: Private mode "map view"]

Here is an example of broken Satellite view :
[image: Private mode "satellite view"]

When looking at the Javascript console, here is what I find :
GET https://khms1.googleapis.com/kh => Error 400 Bad Request
But the request is sent by Google's own js code.

[image: Error 400]

My web app has been working fine for years until I noticed this.

Comment: Hello, I searched for hours but didn't find nothing
I have exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are using a prototype js library, check in your developer console if you are receiving an error from Array.from function, if so, fix this bug in the overrided function or just comment it (at least to test it).

Comment: So what I did is just comment out the line with "Array.from = $A;" in prototype.js That did the trick... See also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58158510/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-to-not-work-correctly
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142335161?pli=1
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139104191#comment3

Comment: Commenting out the Array.from overridden function resolved the issue for me as well. Using the prototype.js has to be avoided or fixed to resolve the map issue.

Comment: Worked for me too. Richfaces has that overrided function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried every available solution on the internet. Turns out Google tag manager was the culprit. How did I come to this conclusion? I opened the network tab in chrome and blocked all the js files from loading. I enabled them one by one and checked if satellite view was loading. For me Google tag manager js file was causing the issue.

[image: Screenshot]